# Replace image color and maintain 100% alpha background

Tags: php, gd

I have a png with a transparent background. The foreground is a single color. I want to change this single color while preserving the 100% alpha background.

The code below doesn't work, it worked when I had a gif. However, when I changed the gif to a png then added the alpha stuff the color change broke down.

If I add `imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 255);` the color is changed but alpha is lost.

Can someone show me where I am going wrong please

```
$imgname = "block.png";
$im = imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
imagealphablending($im, false); 

$index = imagecolorclosest ($im, 153,153,153); // get Grey COlor
imagecolorset($im,$index,0,0,0); // SET NEW COLOR

imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);
$imgname = "result.png";
imagepng($im, $imgname ); // save image as gif
imagedestroy($im);
```

EDIT :: This is a simple enough script.

When I used a gif, the color changed and the new image was saved. When a changed to a .png. The color no longer changed and thus the original image passes through the script unchanged.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" and "it broke down".

Comment: Defining "broke down" as "stopped working" is not useful. :)

Comment: I don't know how to make it any clearer... the script does one thing... it changes one color... it worked with a gif... it doesn't work with a png...

Comment: This approach will *only* work when you're using a graphic file that's using a color palette (number of colors <= 256), so it will never work for 15-/16-/24-/32-bit images.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a PNG-24? As far as I believe that would only work with PNG-8. Maybe you could try to use [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)